# XQuery - return unique values without distinct-values

Tags: xml, xquery

I've come to a complete stand-still regarding a certain XQuery-problem. In the beginning, I did not have multiple exhibits with the same title in the XML-document - when I changed that I noticed a certain problem: the result (in XQuisitor) displays all the names of the guides twice or thrice for each unique exhibit, depending the how many exhibits share the same title.

I have no idea why and would be grateful for some input.

Here's the XQuery code I tried with:

```
for $u in (//Exhibit/@title)
let $guide := for $g in //Guide[../@title=$u]/@gname return element Guide {$g}
return element Exhibit {attribute Title {$u}, $guide }
```

Example XML-document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Exhibits>
<Exhibit title = "Renaissance"  sdate= "2011-09-05"  
edate= "2012-02-05"  sarea = "2400">
<Guide gname = "John Smith" >
<Lang sname ="English"/>
<Lang sname ="German"/>
</Guide>
<Guide gname = "Weber Schneider">
<Lang sname = "German"/>
</Guide>
<Guide gname = "Robert Lundstrom">
<Lang sname = "Swedish"/>
</Guide>
<Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
<Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
<Lang sname = "German"/>
<Lang sname = "English"/>
</Guide>
</Exhibit>
<Exhibit title = "Renaissance"  sdate= "2011-10-06" 
edate= "2011-11-26" sarea = "2000">
<Guide gname = "John Smith">
<Lang sname ="English"/>
<Lang sname ="German"/>
</Guide>
<Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
<Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
<Lang sname = "German"/>
<Lang sname = "English"/>
</Guide>
</Exhibit>
</Exhibits>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some example document which leads to the undesired output.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
let $vals := /*/Exhibit/@title
  return
     for $t in  $vals[index-of($vals, .)[1]]
       return
        element Exhibit 
           { attribute Title {$t},
             let $gvals := /*/Exhibit[@title eq $t]/Guide/@gname
              return
                for $gname in $gvals[index-of($gvals, .)[1]]
                  return
                    element Guide {attribute gname {$gname}} 
           }
```

**When applied on this XML document (the provided one, made slightly more complex)**:

```
<Exhibits>
  <Exhibit title = "Renaissance"  sdate= "2011-09-05"   edate= "2012-02-05"  sarea = "2400">
    <Guide gname = "John Smith" >
      <Lang sname ="English"/>
      <Lang sname ="German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Weber Schneider">
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Robert Lundstrom">
      <Lang sname = "Swedish"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
      <Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
      <Lang sname = "English"/>
    </Guide>
  </Exhibit>
  <Exhibit title = "Renaissance"  sdate= "2011-10-06"  edate= "2011-11-26" sarea = "2000">
    <Guide gname = "John Smith">
      <Lang sname ="English"/>
      <Lang sname ="German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
      <Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
      <Lang sname = "English"/>
    </Guide>
  </Exhibit>
  <Exhibit title = "Middle Age"  sdate= "2011-10-06"  edate= "2011-11-26" sarea = "2000">
    <Guide gname = "John Smith">
      <Lang sname ="English"/>
      <Lang sname ="German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
      <Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
      <Lang sname = "English"/>
    </Guide>
  </Exhibit>
  <Exhibit title = "Middle Age"  sdate= "2011-09-05"   edate= "2012-02-05"  sarea = "2400">
    <Guide gname = "John Smith" >
      <Lang sname ="English"/>
      <Lang sname ="German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Weber Schneider">
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Robert Lundstrom">
      <Lang sname = "Swedish"/>
    </Guide>
    <Guide gname = "Paula Munoz">
      <Lang sname = "Spanish"/>
      <Lang sname = "German"/>
      <Lang sname = "English"/>
    </Guide>
  </Exhibit>
</Exhibits>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Exhibit Title="Renaissance">
   <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
   <Guide gname="Weber Schneider"/>
   <Guide gname="Robert Lundstrom"/>
   <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
</Exhibit>
<Exhibit Title="Middle Age">
   <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
   <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
   <Guide gname="Weber Schneider"/>
   <Guide gname="Robert Lundstrom"/>
</Exhibit>
```

**Explanation**:

We use the fact that for a sequence of atomic values `$vals`:

```
$vals[index-of($vals, .)[1]]
```

produces a set of items with all distinct values contained in `$vals`.

Answer (score 1):

For each unique exhibit, your query finds all guides beneath any exhibits *with the same name* and shows these. If you only want those from the current one, try this query:

```
for $e in //Exhibit
let $guide := for $g in $e/Guide/@gname return element Guide {$g}
return element Exhibit {attribute Title { $e/@title }, $guide }
```

With the input file you provided, your query returns:

```
<Exhibit Title="Renaissance">
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Weber Schneider"/>
  <Guide gname="Robert Lundstrom"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
</Exhibit>
<Exhibit Title="Renaissance">
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Weber Schneider"/>
  <Guide gname="Robert Lundstrom"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
</Exhibit>
```

and the corrected one yields:

```
<Exhibit Title="Renaissance">
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Weber Schneider"/>
  <Guide gname="Robert Lundstrom"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
</Exhibit>
<Exhibit Title="Renaissance">
  <Guide gname="John Smith"/>
  <Guide gname="Paula Munoz"/>
</Exhibit>
```

Comment: Leo Wörteler, I think that the OP wants only one `Exhibit` with all distinct-named `Guide`s to be produced -- see my answer for a solution.